# Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition error creating a new project

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have installed Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition on Vista Home Premium and whenever i try to create a new project, no mater which type(CLR, Console, Win32, Empty project) i get "Creating project 'project name' ... project creation failed." However i can open an existing solution.
So basically my Visual C++ is useless.

Any idea what could i do to get this working? I'd hate to be needed to reinstall the whole OS just to get it working.

I tried uninstalling and installing again multiple times. same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved following the steps in this guide: http://masteranza.wordpress.com/2008/12/27/solution-vs-c-2008-project-creation-failed-bug/ after **a lot** of Googleing

Answer (score 0):

Check if You have access rights to the directory in which Your solution is to be saved.